# Which of these database schemas are more preferable?

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

Just wanna ask your opinion about these database schemas.
Which do you think is more preferable and please tell me why?

Option 1:

> Table Name: Residents
>
> id | name | street_id
>
> 1   | Peter | 1
>
> 1   | John  | 1
>
> Table Name: Streets
>
> id | name
>
> 1 | Rock St.
>
> 2 | Green St.

Option 2:

> Table Name: Residents
>
> id | name | street
>
> 1   | Peter | Rock St.
>
> 1   | John  | Rock St.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. (It always depends! :-)

Option 1 has the advantage that if you need to change the name of "Rock St." to "Rock Rd." then you only need to change one row in the `Streets` table. If you need to change the name of the street in option 2, you may have to change many rows.

Option 2 has the advantage that you don't need to do a `JOIN` query to get the name of the road along with the name of the resident. In general, doing a `JOIN` to lookup the street by its primary key isn't a great cost, but some applications have such a high requirement for performance optimization that they seek to eliminate joins. But honestly, not many applications are so sensitive that they can't do a `JOIN` once in a while.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but just want to ask if there is any significant change in performance for Option 1?

Comment: Is there a difference between updating 1 row vs. updating potentially thousands or millions of rows? Yes, that's a big difference.